# Get Id of Image in next row to use in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns like this :

```
<table width="337" border="1" id="tabel1">
      <tr  >
        <td width="105"><?php echo $row_rsNama['Nama']; ?></td>
        <td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/t-shirt1.png" alt="" width="105" height="179"/ id="T-01"></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/t-shirt2.png" alt="" width="105" height="179" id="T-02"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="img/t-shirt3.png" alt="" width="105" height="179" id="T-03"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the Id of Image in second row for use in the first row to show the name of that data in MYSQL :

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect); 
$query_rsNama = "SELECT Name FROM all_t_shirt WHERE ID ='Image ID in second row'"; 
$rsNama = mysql_query($query_rsNama, $connect) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_rsNama = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsNama); 

?>
```

My question is : how can I get the Image ID in the second row ?

I want to get T-01, T-02, and T-03 to use in MySQL Statement :
SELECT Name FROM all_t_shirt WHERE ID ='Image ID in second row'

Comment: how the html is being generated here ?

Comment: use `mysqli` and dont use `mysql_` it `DEPRECATED`

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "second row" requires an ordering.  After that, you can use `limit` with `offset`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM all_t_shirt
order by id
limit 1, 1
```

The first argument is the offset and the first row has an offset of 0, rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear your question. well as i understand you need to get the image id

```
<?php
$sql="sqlqct name,id from all_t_shirt ";
$fire_sql=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_Object($firesql)){
?>

<tr>
   <td width="105"><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
   <td width="105"><?php echo $data->id; ?></td>
   <td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope it will help you. if not then please explain little bit more about your question.

Comment: I just put the image in HTML like this 
<td><a href="#"><img src="img/t-shirt1.png" alt="" width="105" height="179"/></a></td>

I just want to get that image ID to use in MySQL statement :
"SELECT Name FROM all_t_shirt WHERE ID ='Image ID in second row'";